# google app script in spreadsheets - cell doesnt refresh when custom function loaded from library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making multiple spreadsheets that share custom functions between eachother. 
the structure is like this:

main file - stores function called "COUNTPROVISION". This function is inherited by multiple files called

child file1
child file2
child fileN

Each child file has access to COUNTPROVISION function which is ofcourse custom function. COUNTPROVISION needs multiple arguments that each child file has different. Everything works perfectly - child files fire COUNTPROVISION from library which is inherited from main file. Using that system I can change custom function in main file and all child files instantly use the same, altered function. That works perfectly fine.

Now in my main file i do want to have cumulative data from all child files in table style. So I download them using IMPORTRANGE - data calculated by COUNTPROVISION from child files to main file. So far so good.

So child files inherit custom function and calculate data properly.
My main file downloads the data from child files to cumulative table.

But after a while i found out that my cumulative data in main file has #NAME instead of previously calculated data. 
After checking in child file i found that cells using COUNTPROVISION custom function need to LOAD that function from main file. It takes time and for a while it is #NAME, later it is LOADING, and finally - correct value.
So my cumulative table downloads value #NAME and doesnt refresh.

I found a solution - i just need to open child file, when it loads the function and recalculate it my cumulative table become correct value. But i can not open all the child files to recalculate each time..

The question is: how to make google spreadsheets (or app script) to refresh data in child files (and load all the custom functions) so the main file has proper data instead of #NAME

Here how the function looks in child files:

```
function COUNTPROVISION(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j) {

  var result = main.COUNTPROVISION(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j);
  Logger.log(result)
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you are processing a lot of data? Maybe using different Sheets would be more appropriate than several Spreadsheets.

Comment: it is only 10 parameters which are just numbers from cell so it is 10 numbers. Dont think it is a lot of data..

Comment: This is more of a Spreadsheet issue rather than coding. In case you don't need updating the spreadsheet in 'real time', try in File -> Spreadsheet Settings to set the Recalculation on 'On change and every minute'. Also, consider if it's possible to join all the Spreadsheets in the same one but in different Sheets, as it gives less problems than calling them with Importrange.

Comment: since i do not use now() and other like this functions recalculation is not a solution :(